# Looking for a phrase describing aggregate tax inflow into different-level budgets

Tags: phrase-request

> The project will cost about USD 1 billion of investment money. It will result in the creation of over 200 new jobs in Yekaterinburg, and will generate an estimated RUB 2 billion of annual tax inflows **at different administrative levels.**

Is "at different administrative levels" a good phrase for stating that the taxes will be collected partly on the minicipal level, partly on the regional level, and partly on the federal level?

The tax system in Russia is three-tier, and there is a kind of stock phrase "бюджеты различных уровней" (budgets of different levels) used in journalism. This or that project will bring a particular aggrate inflow into "budgets of different levels".

Multitran [offers several translations](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%E1%FE%E4%E6%E5%F2%FB%20%F0%E0%E7%EB%E8%F7%ED%FB%F5%20%F3%F0%EE%E2%ED%E5%E9) for this stock phrase, but I tried to come up with a different one.

> Multitran's translations: different level budgets (MichaelBurov); various level budgets (MichaelBurov); budgets of various levels (MichaelBurov) different treasuries (AD Alexander Demidov); public coffers (Alexander Demidov)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - Yes

In this case ***different administrative levels*** refers, as you have identified, to different tiers of government.

Administration has many different meanings. Most commonly it is associated with the actions involved in running an organisation or business:

> The action of carrying out or overseeing the tasks necessary to run an organization, bring about a state of affairs, etc.; the process or activity of running a business, organization, etc. - *OED Online*

However, it is also used, with the definite article, as a term for government - *The Administration*:

> The executive part of the legislature; the body of individuals engaged in this; the government; (freq.) spec. the government which is in power at a particular time, or which is led or presided over by a particular individual. - *OED Online*
>
> The administration had to devote the early part of September to trying to change public opinion. *From the NY Times*

You could rearrange the end of your paragraph as:

> ...will generate an estimated RUB 2 billion of annual tax inflows at different levels of the administration.

But I think your original sounds more natural.